# How to drop duplicate rows from postgresql sql table

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

```
date        | window  | points  |    actual_bool      |         previous_bool          |       creation_time        | source 
------------+---------+---------+---------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------+--------
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.6 |                   0 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:20:57.51966  | bldgh
 2021-02-11 |     150 |     0.7 |                   1 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:20:57.51966  | fiata
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.7 |                   1 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:20:57.51966  | nfiws
 2021-02-11 |     150 |     0.7 |                   1 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:20:57.51966  | fiata
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.6 |                   0 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:20:57.51966  | bldgh
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.3 |                   0 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:22:22.969014 | asdg1
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.6 |                   0 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:22:22.969014 | j
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.3 |                   0 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:22:22.969014 | aba
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.5 |                   0 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:22:22.969014 | fg
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.6 |                   1 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:22:22.969014 | wdda
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.7 |                   1 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:23:21.977685 | dda
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.5 |                   1 |                               0 | 2021-02-14 09:23:21.977685 | dd
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.6 |                   1 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:23:21.977685 | so
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.5 |                   1 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:23:21.977685 | dar
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.6 |                   1 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:23:21.977685 | firr
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.8 |                   1 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:24:15.831411 | xim
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.8 |                   1 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:24:15.831411 | cxyy
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.3 |                   0 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:24:15.831411 | bisd
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.1 |                   0 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:24:15.831411 | cope
 2021-02-11 |     110 |     0.2 |                   0 |                               1 | 2021-02-14 09:24:15.831411 | sand
 ...
```

I have the following dataset in a postgresql table called testtable in testdb.

I have accidentally copied over the database and duplicated rows.

How can I delete the duplicates?

Row 1 and row 5 are copies in this frame and row 2 and row 4 are copies too.

I have never used sql before to drop duplicates I have no idea where to start.

I tried

```
select creation_time, count(creation_time) from classification group by creation_time having count (creation_time)>1 order by source;
```

But all it did was show me howmany duplicates I had in each day,

Like this

```
       creation_time        | count 
----------------------------+-------
 2021-02-14 09:20:57.51966  |    10
 2021-02-14 09:22:22.969014 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:23:21.977685 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:24:15.831411 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:24:27.733763 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:24:38.41793  |    10
 2021-02-14 09:27:04.432466 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:27:21.62256  |    10
 2021-02-14 09:27:22.677763 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:27:37.996054 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:28:09.275041 |    10
 2021-02-14 09:28:22.649391 |    10
...
```

There should only be 5 unique records in each creation_timestamp.

It doesnt show me the duplicates and even if i did it would have no idea how to drop them.

Comment: Do you have an id column?

Comment: no i dont, should i have made one?

Comment: Every table should have such a column, e.g. for identifying specific records...

Comment: my first time doing sql, i didnt realise, is there anyway i can fix it now and add an id column after removing the duplicates?

Comment: Add in an id column BEFORE removing what be much more helpful. Because it is quite easy to identify the duplicates, but its harder to remove them if you cannot adress them properly...

Comment: There is system column that can help in the short term, `ctid`.  If you add it to query: `select ctid, * from classification` you will see it is unique for each row. The problem  it is not guaranteed to remain the same over time. That being said look at @GordonLinoff answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a lot of rows to delete.  I would suggest just recreating the table:

```
create table new_classification as
    select distinct c.*
    from classification c;
```

After you have validated the data, you can reload it if you really want:

```
truncate table classification;

insert into classification
    select *
    from new_classification;
```

This process should be much faster than deleting 90% of the rows.

Comment: This is a nice idea! :)

Comment: omg thank you so much, it worked, you saved me so much time. could you explain what the select distinct c.*
    from classification c; of the command does?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * returns your table content without duplicates

Comment: then what does the c.* and c do?

Comment: @anarchy . . . The `c` is a table alias.  The `c.*` returns all columns from the whatever `c` refers to.

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks that makes sense, I’ve never seen this syntax.

Comment: This is why having a primary key on every table is important.  This way you can delete duplicates by only deleting the max(id) key having count(*) > 1

Comment: @eatmeimadanish . . . Even in that case, you would still want to take this route.  Deleting most of the rows in a table is usually way more expensive than simply extracting the rows you want, truncating the table, and re-inserting.